# Provisioning vagrant machine: The Dockerfile (Dockerfile) must be within the build context

Tags: docker, vagrant

I'm trying to build a docker container on the fly in a vagrant vm. The Vagrantfile and Dockerfile the container is to be built from are in the same directory, and on the VM, they are both found in the default synced folder /vagrant as expected. Unfortunately, building the container does not work- I get `The Dockerfile (Dockerfile) must be within the build context`. What is the proper build context in this case? Do I need to copy the Dockerfile somewhere to be able to use it?

Vagrantfile:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
    config.vm.provider "virtualbox"
    config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
    config.vm.hostname = "ubuntu"

    config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.0.200"
    config.ssh.forward_agent = true
    config.ssh.insert_key = false

    config.vm.provision "docker" do |d|
        d.build_image "/vagrant/Dockerfile"
        d.build_args = ['--tag "container"']
        d.run "container"
    end
end
```

Output:

```
$ vagrant provision
==> default: Running provisioner: docker...
==> default: Building Docker images...
==> default: -- Path: /vagrant/Dockerfile
==> default: stdin: is not a tty
==> default: The Dockerfile (Dockerfile) must be within the build context (/vagrant/Dockerfile)
The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!

docker build  /vagrant/Dockerfile

Stdout from the command:



Stderr from the command:

stdin: is not a tty
The Dockerfile (Dockerfile) must be within the build context (/vagrant/Dockerfile)
```

Comment: Is `d.build_image "/vagrant/Dockerfile"` a valid option?  Have you tried `d.build_dir "/vagrant"`?

Comment: Optionally specifying `d.dockerfile x` if the dockerfile is not called "Dockerfile"

Comment: build_dir and dockerfile are not valid settings, according to `VagrantPlugins::DockerProvisioner::Config:
* The following settings shouldn't exist: build_dir`

Comment: what version of vagrant are you running? http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/docker/configuration.html

Comment: Sorry, was looking at the `provider` docs; looks like the `build_image` option is OK, try just putting the path, as in `d.build_image "/vagrant"`

Comment: huh, that seemed to work. no way! thanks, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Glad to help, I'll add it as an answer

Comment: Checkout using Docker machine. Much simpler and faster for setting up an adhoc docker host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `d.build_image "/vagrant/Dockerfile"` option should refer to the containing folder of the Dockerfile, in this case:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
    config.vm.provider "virtualbox"
    config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
    config.vm.hostname = "ubuntu"

    config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.0.200"
    config.ssh.forward_agent = true
    config.ssh.insert_key = false

    config.vm.provision "docker" do |d|
        d.build_image "/vagrant"
        d.build_args = ['--tag "container"']
        d.run "container"
    end
end
```